# Swift WKWebView Padding to hide object

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I am displaying a website in a WKWebView that happens to have a banner at the top of the page. I do not want this banner to be visible to the user. I have tried using JavaScript to remove the banner and this worked until they changed the way the banner works and I cannot remove it anymore.

So, my last resort is to make WKWebView have a negative padding or something similar so that people can't scroll up and it appears like the top of the webpage is after the banner.

Has anyone got any ideas how I can make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, the good way to make sure you dont interfere with the scrolling would be to remove via javascript, but you can try using contentInsets.

```
let webview = WKWebView(frame: self.view.bounds)
webview.scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
webview.scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: -50, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

If the banner is a floater/sticky (scrolls with you and its always showing at the top) this might not work, then you can probably:

- Make your WKWebview taller by adding the same amount of height as the banner
- Have the top constraint of the webview be negative by that amount. (top part will be offscreen)
- That way, the banner will always be there, but never seen as its out of the screen.
- If you webview does not cover the entire screen you can still do this, just make sure that you have a view on the top part of it with a fill color to hide the banner

Comment: The banner is sticky to the top. Is there any other methods?

Comment: Make your WKWebview taller by adding the same amount of height as the banner and have it the top constraint be negative that amount. So the banner will always be there, but never seen as its out of the screen